# Nothing is returned when trying to test php function

Tags: php, testing, localhost

I am trying to test a function in my browser, but nothing is returned. I accessed the link `http://localhost/myfunctions.php?runFunction=writeJSON`
My function is:

```
function writeJSON()
{
    $myfile="testson.json";
    $fileout=fopen($myfile,'w') or die("Fatal: Can't open JSON file for writing");
    global $arrayForJSON;
    if(isset($arrayForJSON))
    {
        fwrite($fileout,json_encode($arrayForJSON));
        echo "done";
    }
    else echo "Error: could not write to JSON file";
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

Where am I mistaken, what is the proper way to test the function, or what am I doing wrong?

The function does not seem to run, since no "done" or "Error: could not write to JSON file" is shown, nor any changes are made to my file.

Comment: is it `echo`ing anything ?

Comment: Well, it seems the function isn't running then.  How do you call the function from within `myfunctions.php`?

Comment: Where do you call this function?

Comment: That's not how you call a PHP function. You need a line like `writeJSON()` at the end of the file.

Comment: Then I really have a problem. I was told that passing it in the URL with runFunction=myFunction will execute my function. The problem is that I need the code to run when a button is clicked somewhere else

Comment: @BujancaMihai No, there is no native way to execute a function from a URL.

Comment: @BujancaMihai - You should be able to adapt Totoro's answer to fit your needs, along with an AJAX call. However, that really needs to be part of the question, since it affects any answers that you receive.

Comment: So still AJAX remains the answer :( I tried to avoid it because I don't know how to use it yet, and I'm quite in a hurry to finish my project. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run a function via a get you need to include the code for the get...

```
//This is the function
function writeJSON()
{
    $myfile="testson.json";
    $fileout=fopen($myfile,'w') or die("Fatal: Can't open JSON file for writing");
    global $arrayForJSON;
    if(isset($arrayForJSON))
    {
        fwrite($fileout,json_encode($arrayForJSON));
        echo "done";
    }
    else echo "Error: could not write to JSON file";
    fclose($myfile);
}


// This will only call the function if ?runFunction=writeJSON
//is on the end of the URL
if(!empty($_GET["runFunction"])){
    if($_GET["runFunction"] == "writeJSON"){
        writeJSON(); // This line is the actual call to the function
    }
}
```

But of course, if you want it to run every time you go to the page just add

```
writeJSON();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to run the function.   Passing it in the url doesn't do anything.

```
<?
function writeJSON()
{
$myfile="testson.json";
$fileout=fopen($myfile,'w') or die("Fatal: Can't open JSON file for writing");
global $arrayForJSON;
if(isset($arrayForJSON))
{
fwrite($fileout,json_encode($arrayForJSON));
echo "done";
}
else echo "Error: could not write to JSON file";
fclose($myfile);
}
writeJSON();
?>
```

Comment: Then I really have a problem. I was told that passing it in the URL with runFunction=myFunction will execute my function.
The problem is that I need the code to run when a button is clicked somewhere else

Comment: There are some frameworks that do that, but I don't think you're using one.

Check out Totoro's response.  He explains how to do it only when you have runFunction set in the url.

Comment: I am just using sublimetext and testing code on my localhost on firefox and chrome